# PHP Image Compression Before Upload

Tags: php, image, upload, compression

I am using an image upload feature found from here (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

With this code, I want to compress the image to a smaller size before it uploads, how do I integrate this with the existing code?

Comment: Use link above to trully procces image *before* upload (i.e. on client side).

If u want to resize image *after* upload (i.e. server side) use smth like old plain GD2 or library like Imagine (just google it)

Comment: The OP asked to compress the image, not resize it.